# Spring Data entityManagerFactory NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, jaxb

I've created a new Spring REST API with [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io) and added JPA, Lombok, PostgreSQL and Spring Web. Sadly I get the following error on startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
```

I could find a lot of material related to this, but none of them seemed to solve this issue for me. What am I missing?

Here's some of my configuration:

`StarterApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StarterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StarterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springapi
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

and my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>design.kde</groupId>
    <artifactId>starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>starter</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Perhaps I'm missing a step in configuration?

Comment: Are you using Java 9?

Comment: remove `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver` and try again

Comment: I am using Java 9 and removing that line does not change the output at all.

Comment: Perhaps I should upgrade to Spring 2+ for Java 9 support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you use Java 9 and adding the following dependency into your pom.xml may help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was using Java 9, thinking that switching to Spring 2.0 will make it compatible, but turns out that's not the case yet. I switched back to Java 8 for compiling this particular app.